# start-stop-daemon not working as expected, no pid file was written

Tags: ubuntu, daemon, start-stop-daemon

I'm trying to control a python based program (which doesn't detach itself from console)

```
#!/bin/bash

user=nobody
pid=/var/run/xx.pid
name=xx
prog=/xx.py

case $1 in
    start)
        /sbin/start-stop-daemon --start -b --oknodo --user "$user" --name "$name" --pidfile "$pid" --startas "$prog" --chuid nobody -- --daemon
        ;;
    stop)
        /sbin/start-stop-daemon --stop --oknodo --user "$user" --name "$name" --pidfile "$pid" --retry=TERM/5/KILL/1
        ;;
    restart)
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac
```

The start part works fine. I can see the script up and running, but the stop part doesn't.
It simply says `No xx found running; none killed.`

So I guess there's something wrong with the start part?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile "$pid"` doesn't write to the pid file unless `--make-pidfile` (`-m`) is specified. Without `--make-pidfile` it is up to the program being launched to create it. Also for `--make-pidfile` to work, the process being launched can't daemonize itself (via a fork), as then `start-stop-daemon` won't know what PID it should put in the file.

The only thing `--pidfile "$pid"` does in your usage scenario is that it will result in `start-stop-daemon` not starting the program if it is already running.

---

If process still is not stopping, all the criteria passed to `start-stop-daemon --stop` must match. Meaning `$pid` has to be a running process, the UID of the process has to match `$user`, and the process name (arg0) has to match `$name`.
You can determine the value of arg0 by doing `ps h -p $pid -o comm`

Comment: Okay the pidfile is written. But stop part still not functioning, same error message

Comment: @warl0ck is the pid file correct, and does the UID of the process match `$user`?

Comment: Yes, I saw start-stop-daemon tried to read `/proc/pid/stat`: `read(4, "5559 (python) S 1 5558 5558 0 -1"..., 1024) = 326`, so the name should be `python` instead perhaps?

Comment: Done, substituted name to `python` and it worked ;-P

Comment: Right, yes, `$name` has to match too. Completely missed that you were passing that in. Will update the answer.